# Use multiple identity files - SSH

Tags: python, docker, ssh

I am trying to download several private Python packages with the use of Docker.

I have the following `requirements.txt`:

```
git+ssh://git@github.com/<myorg>/<myrepo1>.git
git+ssh://git@github.com/<myorg>/<myrepo2>.git
```

and the following `Dockerfile`:

```
...
RUN ssh-keyscan -t rsa github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts && chmod 600 ~/.ssh/
ENV GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/key1 -i ~/.ssh/key2"
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

However, it seems only `key1` is being used and I am stuck with a `Please make sure you have the correct access rights` error for the second repo.

The `man ssh`page says "`It is possible to have multiple -i options (and multiple identities specified in configuration files).`"

How can I source multiple ssh keys to download from different repos on the same host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do this by using an SSH config file:

```
# Repo 1
Host github.com-repo-1
    HostName github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/repo-1

# Repo 2
Host github.com-repo-2
    HostName github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/repo-2
```

And in the Dockerfile:

```
ENV GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -F ~/.ssh/config"
```